# redirect inside chrome app window between 2 local files

Tags: google-chrome-app

can i redirect between 2 local hosted pages inside chrome packaged app window? (chrome.app.window) 
document.location is unavailable, window.location also.
I don't want to use webview..

Answer (score 0):

Navigation is illegal in Chrome Apps. (The windows look like web pages, in that they interpret HTML, but they are not web pages.)

It would help if you indicated what you are trying to do with what you call "redirect".